# Soft select for pandas index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Index, and list of integer positions into that index which might not all exist in that index. E.g.

```
idx = pd.Index(['A', 'B', 'C'])

l1 = np.array([1, 2])
l2 = np.array([1, 4])
```

Now

```
idx.loc # doesn't exist
idx[l1] # => ['B', 'C']
idx[l2] # KeyError
```

How do I get

```
idx.magic(l2)  # => ['B']
```

Right now I'm doing something roughly like

```
pd.DataFrame(idx, columns=['name']).merge(pd.DataFrame(l2), how='left', left_on='name', right_on...)
```

which is gross.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `Index` doesn't provide any special lookups for this case, but you could simply filter the indexer, like this:

```
l2 = l2[l2 < len(idx)]

idx[l2]
Out[15]: Index(['B'], dtype='object')
```